# Prompt needed while saving excel

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, interop

I am Trying to the results of two datasets to excel using the below function. Currently I am able to save it to some location. I want to show a prompt when the user click the Export Button and calls the below function. Currently it saves to My Documents.

```
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class ExportToExcel

    Public Sub DataSetsToExcel(dataSets As List(Of DataSet), fileName As String)
        Dim xlApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
        Dim xlWorkbook As Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet)
        Dim xlSheets As Sheets = Nothing
        Dim xlWorksheet As Worksheet = Nothing

        For Each dataSet As DataSet In dataSets
            Dim dataTable As System.Data.DataTable = dataSet.Tables(0)
            Dim rowNo As Integer = dataTable.Rows.Count
            Dim columnNo As Integer = dataTable.Columns.Count
            Dim colIndex As Integer = 0



            'Create Excel Sheets
            xlSheets = xlWorkbook.Sheets
            xlWorksheet = DirectCast(xlSheets.Add(xlSheets(1), Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing), Worksheet)
            xlWorksheet.Name = dataSet.DataSetName

            'Generate Field Names
            For Each dataColumn As DataColumn In dataTable.Columns
                colIndex += 1
                xlApp.Cells(1, colIndex) = dataColumn.ColumnName
            Next

            Dim objData As Object(,) = New Object(rowNo - 1, columnNo - 1) {}

            'Convert DataSet to Cell Data
            For row As Integer = 0 To rowNo - 1
                For col As Integer = 0 To columnNo - 1
                    objData(row, col) = dataTable.Rows(row)(col)
                Next
            Next

            'Add the Data
            Dim range As Range = xlWorksheet.Range(xlApp.Cells(2, 1), xlApp.Cells(rowNo + 1, columnNo))
            range.Value2 = objData

            'Format Data Type of Columns 
            colIndex = 0
            For Each dataColumn As DataColumn In dataTable.Columns
                colIndex += 1
                Dim format As String = "@"
                Select Case dataColumn.DataType.Name
                    Case "Boolean"
                        Exit Select
                    Case "Byte"
                        Exit Select
                    Case "Char"
                        Exit Select
                    Case "DateTime"
                        format = "dd/mm/yyyy"
                        Exit Select
                    Case "Decimal"
                        format = "$* #,##0.00;[Red]-$* #,##0.00"
                        Exit Select
                    Case "Double"
                        Exit Select
                    Case "Int16"
                        format = "0"
                        Exit Select
                    Case "Int32"
                        format = "0"
                        Exit Select
                    Case "Int64"
                        format = "0"
                        Exit Select
                    Case "SByte"
                        Exit Select
                    Case "Single"
                        Exit Select
                    Case "TimeSpan"
                        Exit Select
                    Case "UInt16"
                        Exit Select
                    Case "UInt32"
                        Exit Select
                    Case "UInt64"
                        Exit Select
                    Case Else
                        'String
                        Exit Select
                End Select
                'Format the Column accodring to Data Type
                xlWorksheet.Range(xlApp.Cells(2, colIndex), xlApp.Cells(rowNo + 1, colIndex)).NumberFormat = format
            Next
        Next

        'Remove the Default Worksheet
        DirectCast(xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count), Worksheet).Delete()


        'Save
        xlWorkbook.SaveAs(fileName, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, _
         XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value)

        xlWorkbook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()
        GC.Collect()
    End Sub

End Class
```

In the Export Button CLick

```
 Dim objExportExcel As New ExportToExcel
  objExportExcel.DataSetsToExcel(dataSets, TotalPAHComponentListDropDown.SelectedItem.Text)
```

Please help me if anyone knows the solution, i have been wasting a lot of time on this.

Comment: I think InputBox() should work in vba.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inputbox if you know the path:

```
iReply = MsgBox(Prompt:="Do you wish to run the 'update' Macro", _
        Buttons:=vbYesNoCancel, Title:="UPDATE MACRO")
```

OR

```
FileDialogs (or Directory):
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'get the number of the button chosen    
Dim FileChosen As Integer
FileChosen = fd.Show

If FileChosen <> -1 Then

'didn't choose anything (clicked on CANCEL)
MsgBox "You chose cancel"

Else

'display name and path of file chosen

 MsgBox fd.SelectedItems(1)

End If
```

(Found at http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s209/type-filedialog.htm)

Comment: Actually I want to save the excel file to the location the user needs. Sorry my bad english

Comment: The file dialog above will prompt the use with an explorer lookup, so that they can choose the location.  No incorrect typos :)

Answer (score 0):

First Put a SaveFileDialog into your Form Then Code a Function that will get all the parameter required into your "Export To Excel"

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim Location As String = Nothing
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Csv files (*.csv)|"
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Location = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
    If Location <> "" Then
          'YOUR EXPORT TO EXCEL FUNCTION
          Export_Data(Parameter1,Parameter2,Parameter3)
    End If
End Sub
```